# Security concerns about running scripts on travis-ci

Tags: bash, security, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I've seen a few tools that recommend downloading a script as part of your continuous integration on travis-ci or other platforms.  I'm worried about the potential for the script that I'm downloading to get compromised and potentially extract some of the encrypted environment variables from my continuous integration server.  What can I do to protect myself from this?  Is there a way to run a script in travis with only certain environment variables and not others?

For example, [here is an example](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash#usage) from codecov.io where they recommend doing the following:

```
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Another example is with Browserstack where [they recommend logging in via http](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/travisci#local-identifier):

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote,
  :url => "http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub",
  :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two options for you I think:

- Run suspect scripts in a completely fresh environment `env -i bash the_script.bash`
- If that's too restricitive (script needs `TRAVIS_COMMIT` for example) you can selectively `unset VARIABLE_NAME` before running the script.